# Write to file using CopyHere without using WScript.Sleep

Tags: vbscript, sleep, wsh

I've written a small VBScript to creates a .zip file and then copies the contents of a specified folder into that .zip file.

I copy the files over one by one for a reason (I know I can do the whole lot at once). However my problem is when I try to copy them one by one without a WScript.Sleep between each loop iteration I get a "File not found or no read permission." error; if I place a `WScript.Sleep 200` after each write it works but not 100% of the time.

Pretty much I'd like to get rid of the Sleep function and not rely on that because depending on the file size it may take longer to write therefore 200 milliseconds may not be enough etc.

As you can see with the small piece of code below, I loop through the files, then if they match the extension I place them into the .zip (zipFile)

```
For Each file In folderToZip.Items
    For Each extension In fileExtensions
        if (InStr(file, extension)) Then
            zipFile.CopyHere(file)
            WScript.Sleep 200
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Any suggestions on how I can stop relying on the Sleep function?

Thanks

Comment: The other way I thought about doing this was making an array and placing all the files that passed the filter into it... but I could use the array in the CopyHere function.

Does anyone know how it?

Comment: No, you could not use the array in any other way than iterating it and doing basically the same thing. What about copying the passed files to a temp folder and add them all at once from there?

Comment: @Tomalak Don't know if that'll make a difference. I think I might get that same error as copying them to a file. How would you add them all at once though?

Comment: By copying/moving the folder object, not the files within. Just a thought. You can also just try and live with it: Set `On Error Resume Next`/`On Error GoTo 0` around the failing statement and loop as long as there is an error. Not particularly nice, I know. :-\

Answer (score 4):

This is how we do it in VB6. After calling `CopyHere` on the zip we wait for async compression to complete like this

```
    Call Sleep(100)
    Do
        Do While Not pvCanOpenExclusive(sZipFile)
            Call Sleep(100)
        Loop
        Call Sleep(100)
    Loop While Not pvCanOpenExclusive(sZipFile)
```

where the helper function looks like this

```
Private Function pvCanOpenExclusive(sFile As String) As Boolean
    Dim nFile       As Integer

    nFile = FreeFile
    On Error GoTo QH
    Open sFile For Binary Access Read Lock Write As nFile
    Close nFile
    pvCanOpenExclusive = True
QH:
End Function
```

Nice side-effect is that even if zipping fails this will not end up in infinite loop.

The trouble comes when accessing the zip-file when it's closed by zipfldr.dll, that is when pvCanOpenExclusive returns true.

Comment: You are assuming quite a lot on what shell is going to do. You are assuming it will only open the file once, and that it will do it the very moment you start the copy (and not, say, half a second later after evaluating source directory properties)

Comment: @EFraim Yes, this is totally hacky and generally not a working approach. One can use `IDropTarget` interface though to zip files synchronously like [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?808681-VB6-Create-a-ZIP-file-without-any-DLL-depends-using-IStorage-and-IDropTarget).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, CopyHere is asynchronous.
When I do this in a vbscript, I sleep until the count of files in the zip, is greater than or equal to the count of files copied in.

```
Sub NewZip(pathToZipFile)

   WScript.Echo "Newing up a zip file (" & pathToZipFile & ") "

   Dim fso
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Dim file
   Set file = fso.CreateTextFile(pathToZipFile)

   file.Write Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, 0)

   file.Close
   Set fso = Nothing
   Set file = Nothing

   WScript.Sleep 500

End Sub



Sub CreateZip(pathToZipFile, dirToZip)

   WScript.Echo "Creating zip  (" & pathToZipFile & ") from (" & dirToZip & ")"

   Dim fso
   Set fso= Wscript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   If fso.FileExists(pathToZipFile) Then
       WScript.Echo "That zip file already exists - deleting it."
       fso.DeleteFile pathToZipFile
   End If

   If Not fso.FolderExists(dirToZip) Then
       WScript.Echo "The directory to zip does not exist."
       Exit Sub
   End If

   NewZip pathToZipFile

   dim sa
   set sa = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

   Dim zip
   Set zip = sa.NameSpace(pathToZipFile)

   WScript.Echo "opening dir  (" & dirToZip & ")"

   Dim d
   Set d = sa.NameSpace(dirToZip)

   ' for diagnostic purposes only
   For Each s In d.items
       WScript.Echo  s
   Next


   ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787866(VS.85).aspx
   ' ===============================================================
   ' 4 = do not display a progress box
   ' 16 = Respond with "Yes to All" for any dialog box that is displayed.
   ' 128 = Perform the operation on files only if a wildcard file name (*.*) is specified. 
   ' 256 = Display a progress dialog box but do not show the file names.
   ' 2048 = Version 4.71. Do not copy the security attributes of the file.
   ' 4096 = Only operate in the local directory. Don't operate recursively into subdirectories.

   WScript.Echo "copying files..."

   zip.CopyHere d.items, 4

   Do Until d.Items.Count <= zip.Items.Count
       Wscript.Sleep(200)
   Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try accessing the file you've just copied, for example with an "exists" check:

```
For Each file In folderToZip.Items
    For Each extension In fileExtensions
        If LCase(oFSo.GetExtensionName(file)) = LCase(extension) Then
            zipFile.CopyHere(file)
            Dim i: i = 0
            Dim target: target = oFSO.BuildPath(zipFile, oFSO.GetFileName(file))
            While i < 100 And Not oFSO.FileExists(target) 
              i = i + 1
              WScript.Sleep 10
            Wend
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

I'm not sure if `target` is calculated correctly for this use context, but you get the idea. I'm a bit surprised that this error occurs in the first place... `FileSystemObject` should be strictly synchronous.

If all else fails, do this:

```
For Each file In folderToZip.Items
    For Each extension In fileExtensions
        If LCase(oFSo.GetExtensionName(file)) = LCase(extension) Then
            CompressFailsafe zipFile, file
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

Sub CompressFailsafe(zipFile, file)
  Dim i: i = 0
  Const MAX = 100

  On Error Resume Next
  While i < MAX
    zipFile.CopyHere(file)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then 
      i = MAX
    ElseIf Err.Number = xxx ''# use the actual error number!
      Err.Clear
      WScript.Sleep 100
      i = i + 1
    Else 
      ''# react to unexpected error
    End Of
  Wend
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code. The loop never runs because FileExists = true. I don't know what it is, but it's not like the file isn't there, but someone the script can't access it to write to it because the previous file hasn't completed it's copying.

Like you said, I would have assumed the copying would be strictly synchronous.

Comment: @mlevit: Maybe comparing file sizes is the way to go?

Comment: @Tomalak I liked that idea so I tried it, however the problems becomes apparent when you reach files of around 20KB or more. Because I'm placing the files into a ZIP file their size shrinks therefore I cannot estimate the ZIP file size with that file in it, my loop becomes infinite.

Comment: @mlevit: Admittedly, I've never actually used the FileSystemObject with zip folders, I did not even know that this was possible. I can only guess that the API function that copies a file to a zip folder works differently than the normal "copy file" API function, and returns a bit too early. Maybe there is no other way than to wait long enough, or to keep trying until the error goes away (via `On Error Resume Next`). Don't forget to include a counter to avoid an infinite loop. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak The script actually continues running after the error is shown but the file that was meant to be copied when the error is show does not get copied across. This is getting so annoying :P

Comment: @mlevit: So the error message is not shown by the script (because error messages *definitely* interrupt the thread), but by the windows API itself? Yes, this really sounds like it would get annoying. Hm, have you tried my suggestion to copy it to a separate folder and compress that folder a a whole?

Comment: Thanks for all your help Tomalak but the error that is thrown is thrown by Windows, not by VB. I'll keep looking around, maybe something will come up. If you want to look at the script it's here: http://gist.github.com/410815

Answer (score 0):

The solution we used after much debugging and QA on various windows flavours, including fast and slow machines and machines under heavy CPU load was the following snippet.

Critique and improvements welcome.

We were not able to find a way of doing this without a loop, that is, if you wanted to do some validation or post zipping work.

The goal was to build something that ran reliably on as many windows flavours as possible. Ideally as natively as possible too.

Be advised that this code is still is NOT 100% reliable but its seems to be ~99%. As stable as we could get it with the dev and QA time available.
Its possible that increasing `iSleepTime` could make it 100%

Points of note:

- The unconditional sleep seems to be the most reliable and compatible approach we found
- The `iSleepTime` should not be reduced, it seems the more frequently the loop runs, the higher the probability of an error, seemingly related to the internal operations of the zip/copy process
- `iFiles` is the source file count
- The more simplistic the loop was, the better, for example outputting `oZippp.Items().Count` in the loop caused inexplicable errors that looked like they could be related to file access/sharing/locking violations. We didn't spend time tracing to find out.
- It seems on Windows 7 anyway, that the internals of the zipping process use a temp file located in the cwd of the compressed zip folder, you can see this during long running zips by refreshing your explorer window or listing dir with cmd
- We had success with this code on Windows 2000, XP, 2003, Vista, 7
- You'd probably want to add a timeout in the loop, to avoid infinite loops

  ```
  'Copy the files to the compressed folder
  oZippp.CopyHere oFolder.Items()
  iSleeps = 0
  iSleepTime = 5
  On Error Resume Next
  Do
      iSleeps = iSleeps + 1
      wScript.Sleep (iSleepTime * 1000)
  Loop Until oZippp.Items().Count = iFiles
  On Error GoTo 0


  If iFiles <> oZippp.Items().Count Then
      ' some action to handle this error case
  Else
      ' some action to handle success
  End If
  ```

Comment: this fails if items are inside folders. If the source folder contains 20 items, it's namespace will report 20, but the zip namespace will still report just 1 item-- the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick I used in VB; get the length of the zip file before the change and wait for it to change - then wait another second or two. I only needed two specific files but you could make a loop out of this.

```
Dim s As String
Dim F As Object 'Shell32.Folder
Dim h As Object 'Shell32.Folder
Dim g As Object 'Shell32.Folder
Dim Flen As Long, cntr As Long, TimerInt As Long
Err.Clear
s = "F:\.zip"
NewZipFolder s
Flen = FileLen(s)
Set F = CreateObject("Shell.Application").namespace(CVar(s))
TimerInt = FileLen("F:\MyBigFile.txt") / 100000000  'set the loop longer for bigger files
F.CopyHere "F:\DataSk\DemoData2010\Test.mdf"
Do
    cntr = Timer + TimerInt
    Do
        DoEvents: DoEvents
    Loop While cntr > Timer
    Debug.Print Flen
Loop While Flen = FileLen(s)
    cntr = Timer + (TimerInt / 2)
    Do
        DoEvents: DoEvents
    Loop While cntr > Timer
Set F = Nothing
Set F = CreateObject("Shell.Application").namespace(CVar(s))


F.CopyHere "F:\MynextFile.txt"

MsgBox "Done!"
```