# Compressing entire files in a particular folder though windows 7 inbuilt capability but through command line

Tags: shell, powershell, windows-7, command-line, batch-file

I want to compress a folder and its all content through command line. It should be similar to when we compress some folder in `windows 7` `64 bit`. 
By right click any folder -> send to -> compress folder.
Is there an equivalent to above process of compressing using command line. I want it through command line as I want to create an batch file.
I can't use any third party tools.

Comment: Check the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1153126/1630171).

Comment: also, this is with vbscript:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888972/write-to-file-using-copyhere-without-using-wscript-sleep  check the top answer

Answer (score 1):

Nativelty?  No, but you can use things like 7-Zip which has command line utilities.  7-Zip is free by the way, and does not need to be installed.

http://www.7-zip.org/

Well, I found a few things you could try with PowerShell:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/daiken/archive/2007/02/12/compress-files-with-windows-powershell-then-package-a-windows-vista-sidebar-gadget.aspx

https://serverfault.com/questions/18872/how-to-zip-unzip-files-in-powershell/201604#201604

This has Command Line and PowerShell solutions :

https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili

Comment: Nope its not allowed in my org, can it be done through .NEt ?

Comment: @Jash Not from the shell and not with no addons

Comment: the last link does not require powershell nor 7 zip and is what you are looking for. I implemented it in some scripts but be aware that it is very hard to detect when the compression is finished.

Comment: @jolivier  I was actually referencing the answer by "Beaner" in the last link which is Powershell but I wasn't really specific, thanks for point it out.

Answer (score 0):

try compact or zip. Compact creates a compressed file while zip is identical to what you are doing folder -> send to -> compress folder

Comment: Please provide a code example since OP indicated wanting to run the compression from the command line.