# vbscript hta freezing on When copying files

Tags: hta, copying

I have an HTA that copies a set of files to a USB stick as a part of creating a usb utilities disk. It works correctly, but the problem is that the HTA becomes unresponsive while the copy process is running.

```
Const FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG = &H0&
sub CopyFiles(driveletter) ' Copys Files to the new USB Disk showing progress bar 

  if radio(0).checked Then 
    Set objFilesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    driveletter = ((driveletter) & "\")
    Set objFolder = objshell.NameSpace(driveletter)
    pathstring = objFilesys.GetAbsolutePathName("c:") 
    objFolder.CopyHere pathstring & "\" & "*.*", FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG
    exit sub
  elseif radio(1).checked Then
    Set objFilesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    pathstring = userselections.txtFile.value   
        if objFilesys.fileExists(pathstring & "\" & "kernel.sys") then
            driveletter = ((driveletter) & "\")
            Set objFolder = objshell.NameSpace(driveletter) 
                    objFolder.CopyHere pathstring & "\" & "*.*", FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG
        Else
            msgbox "Error! The Specified path does not contain valid Install Files", vbcritical 
        end if
  end if 
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that shell.application's CopyHere method is aynchronous -- it doesn't pause execution while you are copying.

"objFolder.CopyHere" starts and "Exit Sub" is called immediately afterwards, causing your code to lose control before CopyHere has completed.

There are some examples of [making CopyHere sort of synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888972/write-to-file-using-copyhere-without-using-wscript-sleep)

[Here's one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fi/clr/thread/760ea95b-4c3e-4f48-a0f6-9d728d5580da) that works for zipping, but could be adapted to your needs.

Comment: HTAs "freezes" for every command they run. For the most build in commands that doesn't matter but things like copying files or parsing documents etc. usally take longer and then you'll notice a freeze.
As mentioned above you could add some pauses to the copy process to make the hta more responsive. Maybe this can give you some extra information: http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Avoid-HTA-interface-freeze-during-long-process-m82946.aspx