# Is it possible to compress(zip) a folder or file from local system(hard drive) using javascript

Tags: javascript, activexobject

Actually I need to compress a folder or file from local system by giving the path in javascript or ActiveXObject in IE browser and store the compressed file.

Example:

I have a folder in D drive called "sample". I need to compress the "sample" folder using javascript and store it in D drive.

zip(D:\sample) // output: sample.zip in D drive

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Scripting.FileSystemObject` and/or `WScript.Shell`. But, do you intend to do that in an HTML page?

Comment: @manuell I am using Scripting.FileSystemObject, Yes i have to implement in Html page.

Comment: Use `Scripting.FileSystemObject` for creating an empty ZIP stream. Then use `WScript.Shell` (the `CopyHere` method from the `Folder` object) for zipping. BEWARE: `CopyHere` with zip destination is asynchronous. If you want to wait for the completion, you'l have to use `setTimeout` and check that the copy is done, comparing items count in the 2 folders, OR checking that you are able to open the zip folder in exclusive mode.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699767/copy-folder-contents-to-a-created-zip-file-file-not-found-or-no-read-permissi and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888972/write-to-file-using-copyhere-without-using-wscript-sleep

Comment: Thank you **Manuell**, I will try the same.